# How do I modify the Powershell console settings in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I go to properties and change the font and buffer size, and when I press okay, I get:

> Unable to modify the shortcut.

I checked to make sure it has not been deleted or renamed.

Comment: Also see http://superuser.com/questions/68013/how-can-i-set-the-powershell-default-window-size-in-windows-7

Answer (score 37):

I've hit the same sort of problem before, and it's mainly because my user account does not have the right access to update the profile.  Try launching the PowerShell console elevated (i.e. right click the PowerShell shortcut in the Start Menu, and click "Run as administrator"), make the changes to the console properties, and close the elevated console.  The settings should stick when you next run PowerShell as you normally do.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Start -> Windows PowerShell, right-click on the icon and choose Copy.

Open the Start -> Programs as a folder and paste the shortcut you just copied. Rename it, say MyPowerShell.

You should be able to modify the settings of this shortcut. Use this shortcut to launch PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Is it pinned? Try unpinning, changing, and repinning.

Answer (score -1):

just right click on the window title,
a menu with "properties" value is going to show,
there you can change font and other settings

Comment: Please note that while the title does note just changing the settings, the body of the question specifically notes that the question is about updating the settings on a shortcut to Powershell, not on the running session. Please read the questions, not just the titles, and make sure your answer answers the actual question.