# How can I set the PowerShell default window size in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

In Windows 7, how can I set the default PowerShell window size? By default it comes up too tall for the netbook screen I am working with.

I have tried the usual way of changing the size—by clicking in the upper-left corner and choosing “Properties”—but it tells me: `Unable to modify the shortcut: . Check to make sure it has not been deleted or renamed.` (yes, there is a dot in the middle of the error message)

I also tried right-clicking on the PowerShell shortcut in the Start menu and changing properties there, however, the changes don’t seem to stick.

Comment: Also see http://superuser.com/questions/36074/how-do-i-modify-the-powershell-console-settings-in-windows-7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a function like this in your profile (`notepad $profile`)

```
Function Set-WindowSize {
Param([int]$x=$host.ui.rawui.windowsize.width,
      [int]$y=$host.ui.rawui.windowsize.heigth)

    $size=New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.Size($x,$y)
    $host.ui.rawui.WindowSize=$size   
}
```

Then call the function:

```
Set-WindowSize 100 50
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, as long as I `Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted`, which is a little worrisome, but I guess I would have to do it eventually to get anything done under PowerShell.

Comment: `setting "WindowSize": "Window cannot be wider than the screen buffer.`

Comment: As for where the $profile file is... https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/

Answer (score 12):

Go `Start` -> `All Programs` -> `Accessories` -> `Windows PowerShell`. RClick on the one you're using. Go to the `Layout` tab, and change the settings you want.

Comment: This works just fine for any shortcut for PS, such as if you've pinned it to your taskbar.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to run Powershell as an administrator.  See [How do I modify the Powershell console settings in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/36074/how-do-i-modify-the-powershell-console-settings-in-windows-7)

Answer (score -1):

You could try Properties, Layout tab, Window Size.

I was also able to grap the top RIGHT most window and re-size in the traditional Windows way.

You could try launching the GUI alternative: PowerShell ISE.