# Why does powershell launch tiny?

Tags: windows-8.1, powershell

My powershell window launches tiny, despite the defaults being fine.

[image]

To adjust I have to go into properties for the window, which fixes it but also displays an error.

[image]
[image]

What can I do to have it launch properly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Powershell font too small on Windows 8.1 - how to adjust?](http://superuser.com/questions/685810/powershell-font-too-small-on-windows-8-1-how-to-adjust)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the properties from an elevated PowerShell command.

One way to do so:

1. From the Start menu, type `pow` and wait for Windows PowerShell to appear in the results list.
2. When it does, right click it and then choose Run as Administrator.
3. When the User Access Control dialog appears, choose Yes.  (Pro tip: Press Left and then hit Enter)
4. When the PowerShell window appears, make your property changes and then exit.

Next time you start the PowerShell window, your changes should now 'stick.'

I *think* (but am not certain) that this happens because the PowerShell shortcut is in a protected directory (e.g. C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools), one that is considered higher integrity than the average directory.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance